# precision in neural network

Tags: neural-network

I am wondering if a neural network is capable of regressing target values that are very close in value. For instance:

```
input [100 150 200 300]
output [0.99903 0.99890 0.99905 0.99895]
```

Or should the output or target data be processed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The three rules of input/output values for a neural network:

1. Normalize your data.
2. Normalize your data.
3. [Normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_%28statistics%29) your data.

Try a few normalization schemes on the data and see how far apart the output points are then. Don't forget to do it to the inputs as well, of course.

[PCA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) can be helpful as well if your data has several dimensions, but this data is one dimensional.

Comment: Thank you. the case I have put here, is an example, the actual problem is multi-dimensional. But for some output variables, the difference is tiny but the tiny difference in value makes the difference, Observation is that the matlab toolbox on its own does not capture this precision, assuming it is used it accurately!!

Answer (score 0):

kwatford is right, normalize your data!

Theoretically neural networks could learn such a target. But we are working on real computers with inprecise real number representations. Now, think about this: you train your neural network and during the training the current prediction is this:

> input [100 150 200 300]
>
> output [0.99905 0.99890 0.99903 0.99895]

I just flipped the results of 100 and 200. Thus, the sum of squared errors will be 4e-10. The values you add to the weights of the neural network will be even smaller. When you use single precision floating point numbers, you will already have a problem with this number. An example in GNU Octave demonstrates this:

```
single(0.99905)+single(1e-10)
ans =  0.99905
```

That means in most ANN implementations it is not possible or: normalize your data. :)

Comment: Thank you very much. I am not an expert user of NN and have been trying to see if for instance the common toolbox in matlab will solve the problem, which I have observed it does not produce accurate enough results. So non-traditional normalization techniques are required for this?

Comment: Traditional normalization techniques will be sufficient. :) Either you can substract the mean and divide by the standard deviation or you can just scale the data to [-1,1].